# Why doesn't dictation work on GBoard in incognito mode?

Tags: chrome-for-android, gboard

My impression was that GBoard dictation works completely locally.

https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/03/an-all-neural-on-device-speech.html

If that's the case, how come it does not work when I go incognito on Chrome? It crosses out the microphone icon in the top right of the keyboard. Did they just forget to disable that feature after they made it work offline?

Comment: Since this is about the internal decision of GBoard, this is probably better to be asked on Google Support instead. One thing is that GBoard's incognito mode (which is automatically enabled when using Chrome's incognito mode) also [prevents GBoard itself from remembering and learning any words you enter](https://www.technobuffalo.com/googles-gboard-keyboard-gets-an-incognito-mode). Possibly it's a side effect of that.

Comment: I don't see how to ask questions on https://support.google.com/gboard